# Inaccurate Laser scan from the Hokuyo sensor Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I have been working on setting up the simulation environment in Gazebo and I have a simple mobile base with the hokuyo sensor on top of it. The laser scan coming out of it seems inaccurate.[image: image description]
I know I am doing some thing silly but I am not able to figure it out. I have attached the necessary code for the Hokuyo sensor. Please let me know if you need anything else from my side.

drsim.xacro

```
<!-- Hokuyo Laser -->
    <link name="base_laser_link">
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://drsim_control/meshes/hokuyo.dae"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1e-5" />
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

drsim.gazebo

 <!-- hokuyo -->
    <gazebo reference="base_laser_link">
        <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <visualize>true</visualize>
            <update_rate>40</update_rate>
            <ray>
                <scan>
                    <horizontal>
                        <samples>720</samples>
                        <resolution>1</resolution>
                        <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
                    </horizontal>
                    <vertical>
                        <samples>1</samples>
                        <resolution>1</resolution>
                        <min_angle>0</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>0</max_angle>
                    </vertical>
                </scan>
                <range>
                    <min>0.10</min>
                    <max>30.0</max>
                    <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                </range>
                <noise>
                <type>gaussian</type>
                    <mean>0.0</mean>
                    <stddev>0.01</stddev>
                </noise>
          </ray>
          
          <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
            <topicName>/base_scan</topicName>
            <frameName>base_laser_link</frameName>
          </plugin>
        
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>
```

Update: I have attached the image after View->Collisions
[image: image description]

Update 2: It turns out that even if I have only the sensor (no mobile robot), I get the same inaccurate laser scan. So, I think the type of sensor is wrong because when I change the type of sensor to "ray" from "gpu_ray" and plugin to libRayPlugin.so from libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so, I get the accurate laser scan as shown:

[image: image description]

But I cant use the new plugin if I want to interface gazebo with ros and get the laser scan data on a ros topic (For example /base_scan). Does anyone have any insights into this?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!
Naman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8221/inaccurate-laser-scan-from-the-hokuyo-sensor-gazebo/) by [Naman91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1129/naman91/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What you observe is a issue due to your graphics card driver. libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so uses the graphics card for generating the simulated laser scan. The other plugin you now employ uses the physics engine (I believe ODE collision checking) for generating the laser scan and is thus unaffected by the GPU rendering issue.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2